# failed loading cafile stream

Tags: php, ssl, curl

When trying to run a application in localhost i got failed loading cafile stream: `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.18\extras\ssl\cacert.pem'
but i set up my php.ini:

```
curl.cainfo ="C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.18\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
openssl.cafile="C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.18\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

my code:-

```
<?php



use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Goutte\Client;

Route::get('/', function () {
    $client = new Client();

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://laracasts.com/skills/laravel');
    $crawler->filter('img')->each(
        /**
         * @param $node
         */
        function ($node) {

            $currentData =  carbon::now()->toDateString();
            $img =  $node->attr('src');
            $imageName = pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $image = $currentData . "-" . uniqid() . "." . $imageName;

            $file = file_get_contents('https://laracasts.com/skills/laravel');



            //     $save =file_put_contents( public_path('image/'.$image),$file);


        }
    );
    return view('welcome');
});
```

i am a newbie learning to code please help me in this regard.

Comment: Add your code please

Answer (score 0):

Your php.ini contains smart quotes (`”`instead of `"`). These quotes are interpreted as part of the filename and make it unaccessible. Always look out for these when copy-pasting code or configuration from the Internet.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i changed( " ) as you suggested, but still getting this error.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, just solved it, i renamed to

```
ca-bundle.crt
```

instead of

```
cacert.pem
```

and it works!